# What is Mario's full name?

Tags: super-mario-brothers

Mario and Luigi are called the Mario brothers. Does that mean Mario's first and last name is Mario, or does he have another first/last name?

Comment: Mario Tiberius Kirk.

Comment: @amaranth Then why did his gravestone say R. for an initial?

Comment: Isn't his first name "Super"?

Comment: @user931 - ....and his last name "Brothers"?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Mario's creator, Shigeru Miyamoto  answered this in [an interview with GameInformer a while back.](https://web.archive.org/web/20180303064422/http://www.gameinformer.com/b/features/archive/2012/09/24/miyamoto-tezuka-interview.aspx)

To him, Mario and Luigi don't have last names, but in the film version, Mario and Luigi have the last name of "Mario".

> “This is an old story, but Hollywood did a film version of the Mario Bros. many years back. There was a scene in the script where they needed a last name for the characters. Somebody suggested that, because they were the Mario Bros., their last name should be Mario. **So, they made him “Mario Mario.”** I heard this and laughed rather loudly. Of course, this was ultimately included in the film. Based on the film, that’s [how] their names ended up. **But, just like Mickey Mouse doesn’t really have a last name, Mario is really just Mario and Luigi is really just Luigi.**”

In 2015, Miyamoto reportedly confirmed that the brothers' last name is officially "Mario", but I have been unable to find a reliable translated source. Most news sources cite [this article about the press conference](http://getnews.jp/archives/1144379); this is the translation courtesy of ixrec.

> 任天堂公式の名称は「マリオ・マリオ」と判明！
>
> The official Nintendo name for him has been confirmed to be "Mario
>   Mario"!
>
> 宮本氏はステージにあがり、「マリオ・マリオが本名」と発言したのである！
>
> Mr Miyamoto came up on stage and stated that "Mario Mario is his real
>   name"!

(note this might be a paraphrase rather than Miyamoto's exact words)

Comment: I didn't realize Mr. Mouse didn't have a last name.

Comment: @imerchant - I'm reasonably sure that mouse is his surname. Perhaps one to ask on another stack

Comment: This is what I found when I went looking... They are just Mario and Luigi. Even found the same interview!

Comment: @Valorum Another stack? How is Mickey Mouse, a character that has studied magic in *Fantasia*, associated with various aliens, and starred in the Kingdom Hearts games **and** the Epic Mickey games, not on-topic here?

Comment: @DrRDizzle - oh, it's on-topic here, it's just a dumb question.

Comment: @Valorum All of a sudden there's something wrong with dumb questions?

Comment: Here's [the question about Mickey Mouse's last name](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/55722/12783) on Movies.SE. It may be a dumb question, but somebody had to ask it.

Comment: @Valorum - I resemble that remark.

Comment: @WadCheber - And slow, too.

Comment: “Name’s Mouse, Mickey Mouse.”

Comment: "Based on the film, that’s [how] their names ended up." That sad moment when you learn that Shigeru  Miyamoto considers something from the movie canonical...

Comment: Poor Luigi Mario. Has to be a Mario no matter what.

Answer (score 114):

From [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario#Surname):

> Nintendo did not initially reveal Mario's full name. In a 1989 interview it was stated not to be "Mario Mario" despite the implication of the Mario Bros. series' title.
>
> The first notable use of "Mario Mario" was in the 1993 live-action film adaptation. This was again used in two of Prima's official stategy guides, in 2000 for Mario Party 2 and in 2003 for Mario and Luigi: Superstar Saga.
>
> In 2012 after Charles Martinet voiced Mario declaring himself "Mario Mario" at the San Diego Comic-Con the next month Satoru Iwata said he had no last name, which Shigeru Miyamoto agreed with the month after. Two months after Iwata's death in July 2015, Miyamoto changed his stance September 2015 at the Super Mario Bros. 30th Anniversary festival, confirming that his name was indeed Mario Mario.

So, TL;DR, the most recent decision is that his first name is Mario and his last name is Mario.

Comment: But what's his first name? ;)

Comment: @user001 Mario.

Comment: Retcon for the win.

Comment: Mario... ±Mario

Comment: So you say its "Mario Mario" and his brother "Green Mario Mario"?

Comment: @user001 going by the film, Luigi Mario

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ydBkyCXfao from the movie where Mario and Luigi are being asked their names.

Comment: First name?  Jumpman.  (See Donkey Kong cabinet art...)

Comment: His first name may be Mario and his last name Mario, because his name is just Mario. That would make his first name and last name together Mario Mario, but his full name just Mario. :-)

Comment: @CaptainMan Mario( Mario)?

Answer (score 5):

The character doesn't have a surname, however he was named after Mario Segale who owned one of Nintendo's first warehouse/distribution centres in America. So if you had to give him a surname then maybe Segale would be an option

One source is linked below, a piece published in the Seattle Times which states that he is a property owner and used to own the warehouse that Nintendo used, and describes that he may have been the inspiration behind Mario being named: [Powerful Segale family has massive vision for Tukwila expanse](http://old.seattletimes.com/html/businesstechnology/2011460764_segale28.html).

Comment: Evidence? Citation? As a statement, it leaves a lot to be desired from an answer.

Comment: I read it in Edge years ago, as for an actual citation, a quick google picked up clickbait and a dead link to a piece of research. This piece from the seattle times may help though http://old.seattletimes.com/html/businesstechnology/2011460764_segale28.html

Comment: @MeatTrademark Miyamoto confirming himself: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uu2DnTd3dEo

Comment: Look at the edit history and the time of my comment. My comment was before the edit.

Comment: Absolutely, your comment prompted me to find some evidence and add to the original answer hence me upvoting your comment, and commenting my edit to state why I had edited it

Comment: -1 because the human that inspired the character is not the same as the character

Comment: Clearly stated in the answer. Though tehcnically he didn't inspire the character. Jumpman existed already, but was later named for Mario

Comment: I don't buy this explanation.  On the Donkey Kong cabinet art, his name was simply "Jumpman". http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-dwazutKnheY/Tkferjs34xI/AAAAAAAAEQE/38vmQjJU-jQ/s1600/Donkey-Kong-Instruction-Sticker-Redo.jpg  The most popular guide to video games book had an explanation that they (the gamers that wrote the book) called him Mario because he "looked Italian".

Comment: -1 from me as well, plenty people are named after other people, that doesn't automatically mean that they inherit the other person's surname

Answer (score -1):

In *The Super Mario Bros. Super Show!* Luigi and Mario's last name is Pisano.

Comment: Hi there! :) Could you [edit] in a source for that? Maybe a clip or a screenshot? That would make for a better answer.

Comment: Isn't that what they call the audience? I don't remember that actually being used as a legal name anywhere.