# What is Princess Zelda's full name?

Tags: video-games, the-legend-of-zelda

In the multiple editions of the *The Legend of Zelda* franchise, have we ever learned Princess Zelda's full name?

Does she simply just go by the name Zelda or perhaps Zelda of Hyrule (a more classical last name derived from the country)?

[image: Princess Zelda]

Comment: How many characters in the Zelda universe have surnames to begin with? You might be asking about something that, for the most part, just doesn't exist in their universe.

Comment: Worth noting is that Zelda has been reincarnated many times, and there's no reason to suppose her "full name" would be consistent among the many incarnations.

Comment: Based on [previous Nintendo naming conventions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/131712/2677), I really want to say her name is Zelda Zelda.

Comment: Which Zelda? Of the 19 LoZ games, 14 contain a character called Zelda and only one of them is a direct sequel but, even then, the Zelda in the game is a different Zelda from the previous installment.

Comment: @geewhiz Not entirely true. Majora's Mask was a sequel to Ocarina of Time, and Zelda appears as a figment of Link's memory. And Spirit Tracks was a sequel to Phantom Hourglass, which was set years apart, so the two Zeldas are likely related. So that's two 'direct sequel's.

Comment: @Pharap Fair point on the sequels. I forgot that "Zelda" appeared in MM. I haven't played ST or PH so I can't speak to those. HOWEVER, I think my main point stands since figments and possible relations are not the same person. Also, it makes 3 direct sequels. Adventure of Link, Majora's Mask and Spirit Tracks. None of which contain the same Zelda (in the flesh anyway) as the previous game.

Comment: @geewhiz Actually, that makes 4, I've just remembered A Link Between Worlds was supposed to be a sequel to A Link To The Past. Technically PH was also supposed to be a sequel to WW, so the Zelda/Tetra in WW and PH is definately the same Zelda. Every other case I can think of is plausibly not the same Zelda except for that one.

Comment: [Zelda Williams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zelda_Williams)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Assuming she follows the same patterning as her relative ([King Daphnes Nohansen ***Hyrule***](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Daphnes_Nohansen_Hyrule)) her full name and title would be **Princess Zelda Hyrule**.

That being said, her name is given in **all** of the games and additional materials as simply Princess Zelda, so it's far more likely that her name is a [mononym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mononymous_person) and that her full name (including formal title) is *"Princess Zelda **of** Hyrule"*, as noted in the instruction manual for The Legend of Zelda - Four Swords Adventures.

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[The Legend of Zelda - Four Swords Adventures](http://zeldacapital.com/manual/fsamanual.pdf)</sup></sub>

and

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[The Adventure of Link - Gameboy Manual](http://zeldacapital.com/manual/taolmanual.pdf)</sup></sub>

and

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[Ocarina of Time - N64 Manual](http://zeldacapital.com/manual/ootmanual.pdf)</sup></sub>

and

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[Oracle of Season - Gameboy Colour Manual](http://zeldacapital.com/manual/oosmanual.pdf)</sup></sub>

Comment: May I inquire why you frequently comment an answer on the question, then post a full answer, then leave the comment? lol

Comment: @jpmc26 He left about an hour's gap. I have done this when I see a question perhaps on my mobile and I just comment really quickly. Then some time later I come back and notice that no one has yet posted a researched answer. If I have the time at that time, or later if another answer still hasn't been put up, I'll type up a full answer that wouldn't fit in a comment. I suppose not deleting the comment is a little lazy but comments aren't such a big deal that I think about it too much.

Comment: @ToddWilcox No, the gap is only about 4 minutes, barely enough time to even write the original answer between them. Comment was 12:27Z and answer is 12:31Z. You can see that in the tool tip for the "x hours ago" stamp on them. So it seems strange to even bother commenting.

Comment: @jpmc26 we generally dont have as stringent of a comment clean up policy on this site as the other SE might have.

Comment: @jpmc26 Ah, I was just commenting at exactly the time that the answer said "two hours ago" and the comment said "three hours ago".

Comment: @jpmc26 - I tend to post my (first) thoughts and musings while I'm deciding whether to answer the question. In this instance, my comment (Princess Zelda of Hyrule) turned out to be correct. Normally I'd delete such comments afterwards but I forgot. As to the distance between the answers, what you're not seeing (on the timestamp) is the 10+ minutes of ninja-edits I did after posting my original answer.

Comment: Surnames are a more recent development than royal titles; for instance the British royal family don't really have a surname (they adopt varying surnames for contexts which need them). So for example Prince Harry's full name is simply 'Henry Charles Albert David', no full name required. He uses 'Wales' in his military service.

Comment: @dbmag9 - It may interest you to know that it's only the Queen who doesn't have a passport. All the other royals hold one. Charles as Charles Windsor, William as William Wales, etc.

Comment: @Valorum Doesn't mean they would consider 'Windsor' etc. to be their surname. The photos at http://theroyalpost.com/2015/09/13/royal-passports/ suggest that when the form allows they don't use one.

Comment: @dbmag9 - I guess unless we can track down a royal and ask them, it's difficult to know what they would consider to be their "real name"

Comment: @Valorum Well yes, but my point was that formally speaking the royal princes do not have a surname. They use one in contexts when it's unavoidable, and they belong to the Royal House of Windsor, but their full names don't include a surname. To bring it back onto topic, it would be totally in line with historical and modern practice for Zelda's full name to be just 'Zelda'.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm firmly convinced Valorum has a direct neural interface to Stack Exchange. You saw two posts close together because was having two thoughts at the same time. :)

Comment: @Valorum You cited one of her relatives, but I'll point out that the name of her father in Breath of the Wild is King Rhoam Bosphoramus Hyrule.

Answer (score 17):

I have come to the conclusion that Nintendo sucks at naming characters... After much looking it seems that she is simple Princess Zelda or Princess of Hyrule, Princess of Destiny, Her Majesty, Spirit Maiden.

Other than the few times she has appeared in games as other characters (I dunno why). She has appeared as Sheik, Tetra, The Leader of the Sages, The Goddess Hylia.

I have managed to dig up the fact that she was named after F. Scott Fitzgerald's wife Zelda Fitzgerald.

> Shigeru Miyamoto stated that the Princess Zelda's name originated from Zelda Fitzgerald, the wife of the acclaimed author, F. Scott Fitzgerald.[125] The name "Zelda" ultimately derives from "Griselda," which may come from the Germanic elements gris ("gray") and hild ("battle").

I think someone needs to talk to Nintendo about properly naming there characters! Or at least making an official list of their names like "Yes this character is called X".

[source](http://zeldawiki.org/Princess_Zelda#Trivia)

Comment: nice finds, on her other names and origin.

Comment: Thanks... Not sure if it helps much though in the long run!

Comment: At least there is a standard romanization of her name.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Is there? I thought that is changed due to what country the games is in? Yeah in the wiki that I quoted it lists all of here names in different languages - Japanese -  ゼルダ姫 (Zeruda hime), Spanish - Princesa Zelda , French - Princesse Zelda, Germany - Prinzessin Zelda, Italy - Principessa Zelda, Russian - Зельда (Zel'da), South Korea - 젤다 공주 , Taiwan, Hong Kong and Macau - 薩爾達 公主 (Sà'ěrdá Gōngzhǔ), Mainland China -  塞尔达 公主 (Sài'ěrdá Gōngzhǔ)

Comment: @Rincewind: All of the languages that use the Roman alphabet use the same spelling for her name, so it looks like there is a standard Romanization for it.

Comment: @jwodder Ah....

Answer (score 8):

There is no canon answer to this. Only a handful of Zelda's relatives are mentioned throughout the games. Many of them go unnamed but there are a few that are named, all of them kings. King Daltus from The Minish Cap has not last name, and neither does King Harkinian from the comics, cartoon and games of dubious canoninity.

The interesting one is King Daphnes Nohansen Hyrule from The Wind Waker. His last name is the same as the realm's name, which befits a ruling monarch. He did have a daugher, the antediluvian princess of whom we see a painting in Hyrule Castle. If her name was Zelda then in that case she was Princess Zelda of Hyrule.

So what is this "Hyrule", then? When one has a noble title this is often referred to as "of X". This does not mean that this is your last name: it's a title. Real life princesses like [Princess Amalia of Orange-Nassov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catharina-Amalia,_Princess_of_Orange) can have this (this particular princess has three of such titles), but only one refers to her dynasty (but no family name). As for the actual name of Hyrule in Daphnes Nohansen's nme this is an interesting case: it seems to be his actual last name.<sup>[1]</sup> Where does this come from? I am uncertain, but if I had to use conjecture I'd say that he's the product from another family whose name is actually Hyrule.

So what does this mean for Zelda's name? Well, her name's just that. **Zelda**. The afmore-mentioned king would be **Daphnes Nohansen Hyrule**. Including their titles this would be **Princess Zelda of Hyrule** and **King Daphnes Nohansen Hyrule**.

---

<sup>[1]: In Japanese he's called Dafunesu Nohansen Hairaru, while King Daltus is called *Hairaru-ō Darutasu*. The former is a name, while the latter is a title. Whether or not this was done intentionally<sup>[2]</sup> is uncertain.</sup>

<sup>[2]: The Minish Cap was developed by Capcom, not Nintendo. It is unknown if these two issues are related.</sup>

Comment: "Oranje-Nassau" is actually just the last name of our royal family. It started with Count Willem van Nassau-Dillenburg, prince of the French region Orange and therefore often called Willem van Oranje. When Willem III died, His nephew off the house Nassau-Dietz adopted the surname Oranje-Nassau and it has been the family's surname ever since.

Comment: There's also King Rhoam Bosphoramus Hyrule from Breath of the Wild, who was the father of that game's reincarnation of Princess Zelda.