# What is the Origin of Link's name?

Tags: names, the-legend-of-zelda

In the Legend of Zelda series the protagonist is always named Link.  We know Zelda's name was based on a real world thing from [What is Princess Zelda's full name?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132400/what-is-princess-zeldas-full-name).

Why/how did the creator come up with such a weird name?

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44694/discussion-on-question-by-himarm-what-is-the-origin-of-links-name).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In a [2012 interview](http://www.gamekult.com/actu/miyamoto-la-wii-u-et-le-secret-de-la-triforce-A105550.html), Shigeru Miyamoto said that the name came from the fact that the character was supposed to be a literal "link" between two different time periods:

> It's not a very well known anecdote, but when we started designing The Legend of Zelda, we imagined the Triforce fragments to be electronic chips! It was supposed to be a video game that would take place in both the past and the future. Because the hero was the link between them, we called him "Link". But in the end, Link never went to the future and it stayed a game of *heroic fantasy*. We can even say that there was never anything futuristic about it!

In his foreword to [*Hyrule Historia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Hyrule_Historia), he gives a slightly (*very* slightly) different explanation:

> We named the protagonist Link because he connects people together. He was supposed to spread the scattered energy of the world through the ages.
>
> <sup>*The Legend of Zelda: Hyrule Historia* On the 25th Anniversary of *The Legend of Zelda*</sup>

Comment: Then in another interview, he explains that Link is the link between the game and you, the user.  
TLDR: Miyamoto makes it up on the fly.

Comment: @Axelrod Kind of surprising he hasn't gone to the 'Link is _a_ legendary hero of time, so he's a _link_ in a _chain_.' type explanation yet. ;)

Comment: @Axelrod Do you have a link for that interview? I remember reading that when I was a kid (in the *Ocarina of Time* strategy guide, I think), but I haven't been able to find a source today

Comment: That sounds a lot like what they ended up doing in the third game, *A Link to the Past*.

Comment: [E3 2010 - Ten minutes with Shigeru Miyamoto](http://gonintendo.com/stories/134253-e3-2010-ten-minutes-with-shigeru-miyamoto) One of a few where he talks about Link being an avatar, etc. Not finding a direct link to him just saying that, but it appears to be Nintendo's current stance on it.

Comment: @Axelrod Not sure I agree with that interpretation. It seems more like Miyamoto is talking about the effect of the motion controls rather than the role of the character

Comment: Possibly worth a comment:  the Japanese name 「リンク」"rinku" is literally just the English word "link", borrowed into Japanese with the same meaning.  So this is a rare case where there's no ambiguity in the translation.