# Who are Mario (and Luigi's) parents?

Tags: movie, video-games, super-mario-brothers, super-mario-bros-1993

We see in the Hollywood movie Super Mario Bros. that no-one seems to know Mario's full name or his background.

So I just want to know, **who are his parents and where do they live? Are they still alive?**

Comment: His first name is obviously *Super*..

Comment: @Bat: It is a big question that its name is 'Super Mario' but officially set 'Mario Mario' so which is corrected?

Comment: That was a joke. Mario Mario is correct one.

Comment: [What is Mario's full name?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131712/what-is-marios-full-name/131714#131714)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We know that his mother [Mama Mario exists](https://www.mariowiki.com/Mama_Mario). She was also living with [Papa](https://www.mariowiki.com/Papa), but it's not clear whether he was really father of Mario and Luigi.

Also, there are other bunch of [Mario's parents theories in existence](http://someordinarygamers.wikia.com/wiki/Mario%27s_Parents_Theory). But, we don't have official words on this.

Comment: What about his parents? This is the main question.

Comment: @AnandPandey Updated.

Comment: Only the final two paragraphs are relevant here. I've edited out the info about his full name since you appear to be answering the question in Anand's comment rather than the question above

Answer (score 5):

The answers really depends on which canon you use.

#### Game Canon

Their parents do exist (see Yoshi's Island) but don't play a large role in the games.

The parents live together in a small cottage in the hills, probably near the Mushroom Kingdom, but I am not sure if they are still alive.

#### TV Canon

Their mother appears in the live action segements, which takes place in New York. We don't know about their father.

#### Amada Anime Series

The only story that has Mario's parents is Issun-bōshi. They live in a cottage near a river, and are probably still alive at the end of the story.

#### Super Mario Bros. Canon(1993)

(Disclaimer: I have never watched the Super Mario Bros. movie.)

We don't know if their parents exist in this canon.

#### The Super Mario Brother Movie(2023)

They have a whole family, which includes a mother and father.

Comment: This would be better if you could [edit] in some evidence of each.

Answer (score -3):

mario parents are probably jumpman and pauline they probabbly have the same name as they sons mario and pauline, whe can see that the pauline from donkey kong is not the same of the later games because of the color of their hair who is  brown, even tought the original pauline hair was blonde, this can be disproved by some interview or romantic interest betwen mario(the modern) and pauline(the modern) if this appened and i don't am nowing,it means that my theory is wrong, so theres other explanation: mario and luigi parents are not revealed and probably will never be, because they live in the marios homeworld(an world similar to our world who mario lived before being transported to the mushrom kingdom) and this place probably will never be visited again. The only thing we now about them is that mario and luigi dont liked them to much or they are just dead because mario and luigi dont seem to miss them and not even mention them

Comment: Again, this seems like a personal theory; do you have any evidence for it?

Comment: this teory already existed i only tinked the part of jumpman name being mario and that the modern pauline is mario sister